# Create Web Service as SDK

Tags: c#, wcf, web, sdk, vs-web-application-project

I want to build a C# Web Service application that needs to be shippable to the 3rd party customers as SDK with UI as well as without UI.

My idea is create a WCF service and host that in Windows Service and made an installer.

Then create a responsive Web application that consumes the windows service so that it be accessed by any browser(Mobile + PC). If the client doesn’t prefer our UI and if they want to consume the SDK alone, then they have to use our windows service and integrate that in their UI.

Any advice on this?

Comment: How and where do you plan to host that web application?

Comment: I have to host that application in Windows server machine. Regarding how, I have to give that application as installer